# After_Refresh Event not triggering for QueryTables wrapped in Listobjects (created with Power Query) if refreshing in the background

Tags: excel, vba, class, events, powerquery

Question also asked here: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/querytable-class-events-not-working-for-querytables-within-listobjects.1117962/

When I try and do a background Refresh on a QueryTable within a ListObject **[created via Power Query]** the After Refresh Event doesn't trigger. However, if I do a non-Background refresh **or** use a vba generated QueryTable, it does trigger the event.

Class File

```
Private WithEvents MyQueryTable As Excel.QueryTable

Friend Sub HookUpQueryTable(Query_T As QueryTable, Procedure_2_Run As String, WB As Workbook, _
                                    VAR As Worksheet, Non_ListObject_QueryTable As Boolean, _
                                    Optional Weekly_Data_Sheet As Worksheet)

Dim Query_Info As Variant

Query_Info = Array(Query_T, Procedure_2_Run, WB, VAR, Non_ListObject_QueryTable, Weekly_Data_Sheet)

WB.Event_Storage.Add Query_Info, Procedure_2_Run 'Workbook_Object.Collection

Set MyQueryTable = Query_T      'Query Table

End Sub


Private Sub MyQueryTable_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)

Dim Query_Object As QueryTable, QT_Workbook As Workbook, Procedure_2_Run As String, Variables As Worksheet, _
Y As Long, Weekly_WS As Worksheet, Non_ListObject_QueryTable As Boolean

Set QT_Workbook = MyQueryTable.Parent.Parent

    If Success Then

        'Determine which query just refreshed
        For Y = 1 To QT_Workbook.Event_Storage.Count

            AR = QT_Workbook.Event_Storage(Y)

            If AR(0) Is MyQueryTable Then           'Loop until the refreshed Query is found

                Set Query_Object = AR(0)            'Query that was refreshed
                Procedure_2_Run = AR(1)             'Procedure to run with parameter
                Set Variables = AR(3)               'Optional addition Saved Variables worksheet
                Non_ListObject_QueryTable = AR(4)   'Boolean that determines if QueryTable is wrapped in a listobject
                Set Weekly_WS = AR(5)               'Data sheet that contains weekly refreshable data

                Select Case Procedure_2_Run

                    Case "Time_Zones_Refresh", "Release_Schedule_Refresh"

                        Application.Run "'" & QT_Workbook.Name & "'!" & Procedure_2_Run, Query_Object, Non_ListObject_QueryTable

                    Case "MAC_Update_Check"

                        Application.Run "'" & QT_Workbook.Name & "'!" & Procedure_2_Run, Query_Object

                End Select

                QT_Workbook.Event_Storage.Remove (Y) 'remove Query array from collection

                Exit For

            End If

        Next Y

    End If

End Sub
```

My usage:

```
Private Sub Time_Zones_Refresh(Optional QT As QueryTable, Optional Non_ListObject_QueryTable As Boolean)

Dim Query_Events As New ClassQTE, QT_Method As Boolean, ListOB_RNG As Range, Result As Variant, _
Query_Exists As Boolean, URL As String

'After Background Query has finished run this procedure again using an event but supply a QueryTable
'To skip the refresh portion, do additional parsing if needed and then start the next background Query

If QT Is Nothing Then

    #If Mac Then

        QT_Method = True

    #Else

        If Application.Version < 16# Then 'IF excel version is prior to Excel 2016 then

            If Not IsPowerQueryAvailable Then QT_Method = True 'Check if Power Query is available

        End If

    #End If

    'PROBLEM IS IN THE ELSE STATEMENT BELOW

    If QT_Method Then

        For Each QT In QueryT.QueryTables           'Determine if QueryTable Exists
            If InStr(1, QT.Name, "Time_Z") > 0 Then 'Instr method used in case Excel appends a number to the
                Query_Exists = True                 'QueryTable Name
                Exit For
            End If
        Next QT

        If Not Query_Exists Then 'Create QueryTable

            URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ubpPnoj7hQkMkwgLpFwOwmFftWI4yN3jMihEshVC89A/export?format=csv&id=1ubpPnoj7hQkMkwgLpFwOwmFftWI4yN3jMihEshVC89A&gid=0"

            Set QT = QueryT.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & URL, Destination:=QueryT.Range("A1"))

            With QT
                .Name = "Time_Z"
                .WorkbookConnection.Name = "Time_Zone_Info"
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
                .AdjustColumnWidth = False
            End With

        End If

    Else

        'THIS IS WHERE THE LISTOBJECT WRAPPED QUERYTABLE IS

        Set QT = Variable_Sheet.ListObjects("Time_Zones").QueryTable

    End If
    '[  Query Object, Procedure to Call after refresh,  Workbook Object, Variable Worksheet ,
    '   Querytable ListObject boolean,Optional Worksheet ]

    Query_Events.HookUpQueryTable QT, "Time_Zones_Refresh", ThisWorkbook, Variable_Sheet, QT_Method, Weekly
                                  '0                1                    2               3         4         5
    QT.Refresh True

Else 'Queries have been refreshed

    Set ListOB_RNG = Variable_Sheet.ListObjects("Time_Zones").DataBodyRange 'Destination range

    If Non_ListObject_QueryTable Then 'store range in array and clear contents

        With QT.ResultRange

            Result = .Value2
            .ClearContents

        End With

    End If

    With ListOB_RNG

        If Non_ListObject_QueryTable Then .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(Result, 1), UBound(Result, 2)).Value2 = Result

        .Rows(3).Value2 = Array("Local Time", Now)

    End With

    Call Release_Schedule_Refresh

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Same problem here.